# Spark SQL Scala - Fetch column names in JDBCRDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark and Scala. I am trying to fetch contents from a procedure in SQL-server to use it in Spark SQL. For that, I am importing the data via JDBCRDD in Scala (Eclipse) and making an RDD from the procedure.

After creating the RDD, I am registering it as a temporary table and then using sqlContext.sql("Select query to select particular columns"). But when I enter column names in the select query, it is throwing an error as I do not have column names in neither RDD, nor the temporary table.

Please find below my code:

```
val driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
val url = XXXX
val username = XXXX
val password = XXXX
val query = "select A, B, C, D from Random_Procedure where ID_1 = ? and ID_2 = ?"

// New SparkContext 
val sc = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Amit")
val sparkContext = new SparkContext(sc)

val rddData = new JdbcRDD(sparkContext, () =>
DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password),
query, 1, 0, 1, (x: ResultSet) => x.getString("A") + ", " +
x.getString("B") + ", " + x.getString("C") + ", " +
x.getString("D")).cache()

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sparkContext)
import sqlContext.implicits._
 val dataFrame = rddData.toDF

dataFrame.registerTempTable("Data")
sqlContext.sql("select A from Data").collect.foreach(println)
```

When I run this code, it throws an error: cannot resolve 'code' given input columns _1;

But when I run:
    sqlContext.sql("select * from Data").collect.foreach(println)
It prints all columns A, B, C, D

I believe I did not fetch column names in the JdbcRDD that I created, hence they are not accessible in the temporary table. I need help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you create JdbcRDD object and you need [DataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame). RDD simple doesn't contain information about mapping from your tuples to column names. So you should create DataFrame from jdbc source as it explained in [programming guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases) Moreover:

> Spark SQL also includes a data source that can read data from other
>   databases using JDBC. This functionality should be preferred over
>   using JdbcRDD

Also notice that DataFrames are added in Spark 1.3.0. If you use older version you have to operate with `org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD`

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Now i have a dataframe having contents of an sql record. I created a temp table from that, and when I run sql.context on it having joins, it doesnt work properly, but the query runs properly in sql server management studio. Will I not be able to run a query with joins on a temp table in spark.